# Kleiber's Law (negatiive quarter-power scaling) of Metabolic rates v/s Mass Compared to Geoffrey West's observation on City Size & Innovativeness

Tags: applications

**Kleiber's Law** states that *metabolism scales to mass to the negative quarter-power*. From this it follows that an elephant which is about 1000 times heavier than a chipmunk would, on an average, have metabolic rate `1000 ^ (1/4)` i.e. `~5.5` times that of the chipmunk.

**Geoffrey West** applied Kleiber's Law to Cities and observe similar scaling of a city's size to it's energy utilization. So a city A 50 times larger than city B would utilize `50 ^ (1/4)` i.e., `~2.6` times as much energy.

**Steven Johnson**'s book *Where Good Ideas Come* From mentions that the only aspect of a city that didn't follow the same pattern, but a **positive instead of negative quarter-power scaling**, was innovativeness of a city w.r.t. it's size. He then goes on to say a city `10` times larger than another would be `17` times as innovative. Also, a metropolis `50` times larger than a town would be `130` times as innovative... Having difficulty following how the math works out in these cases.